# TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a loop in my html form inputs to check it's values. I'm doing this in every page I access via chrome-extension. Some pages it works very nice, but other ones, I keep getting the error

> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

The line where I always get this error is:

> var FieldValue = details.requestBody.formData[ReceivedInputs[aux]][0];

ReceivedInputs is one array with the name of all the forms inputs the page have. And I tried to avoid the error by doing:

> if (undefined != ReceivedInputs[aux])

The loop to retrieve the values is:

```
for(var aux=0;aux<ReceivedInputs.length;aux++)
    {
        if (undefined != ReceivedInputs[aux])
            {
                var FieldValue = details.requestBody.formData[ReceivedInputs[aux]][0];
                alert(FieldValue);
            }
    }
```

Anyway to successfully check if the variable is not undefined? I tried

> if (typeof ReceivedInputs[aux] != 'undefined')

too. And some other sugestions, but keep getting the error...

Comment: `console.log(ReceivedInputs[aux]); console.log(details.requestBody.formData[ReceivedInputs[aux]]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check:

```
if (ReceivedInputs[aux] && details.requestBody.formData[ReceivedInputs[aux]]) {
   var FieldValue = details.requestBody.formData[ReceivedInputs[aux]][0];
   ...
```

because value from `ReceivedInputs[aux]` is used as an index to `details.requestBody.formData` array.

Comment: Uhmm... I'm not experienced on JavaScript. Anyway, I did what you said, and looks like it's giving much less errors but I still getting some. And now is like this: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'q' of undefined`... How that's possible, property 'q'? I'm trying to retrieve [0], can't understand...
_EDIT: looks like 'q' is one field from the last page visited. I think i'm getting this error because 'q' is not present anymore in the actual page, but I didn't cleaned the array..._

Comment: @user2864778 - so it's a whole another issue then ;)

Comment: Yes... I couldn't test more, but I'll accept your answer. Thank you!